# How do I remove unwanted sensors from the psensor main panel?

Tags: gui, temperature, sensors, lm-sensors, psensor

Is there any way to remove the other sensors that I am not drawing on the graph?
[image: psensor]

I would have thought that the option under *Psensor -> Sensor Preferences* -> *"Display sensor in the Application Indicator menu"* implies it would not be listed in the right-hand panel of the main screen.

Unticked boxes showing what I would have assumed removes this sensor from the main screen:

[image: unwanted sensor]

The opposite:

[image: wanted sensor]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This setting is corresponding to the Ubuntu Application Indicator menu, it does not affect the displaying of the sensor in the main window.

Until the v1.1.1 release, the only way to remove a sensor from the main window is to edit the lm-sensor configuration, there is no such setting at Psensor level. See "man sensors.conf" and the statement "ignore".
The syntax is something like:

chip "fschds-*"

ignore fan1

BTW, since psensor v1.1.1 it is possible to show/hide a given sensor directly at psensor level and for all sensors (sensor preferences > display sensor in the list of sensors).

Comment: Would you then elaborate and make your answer complete?

Comment: Edited (new feature in 1.1.1)